# Pressure and force of ideal gas in a leaking container?

Tags: forces, pressure, ideal-gas

Let's imagine you have a container that has a pressure of *10 Pascals* inside and a vacuum outside. The container has a volume of a cubic meter and I'm not sure if the temperature matters but lets say it's 293.5k. A small hole with an area ***A*** of a square millimeter is punctured into the wall of the container. Would the pressure exerted by the escaping air be greater than *10 pascals* initially or would it be *10 Pascals* exactly? And how many Newtons would be there exerted on ***A***? I'm guessing that the pressure is 10 N/m^2 but since the area is smaller than a *meter squared* then the force in Newtons must be larger? Or does the pressure stay the same but the Newtons become larger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force would be proportional to the area, so the force on the hole would be 10^(-5) N

Comment: But would the pressure be 10 Pascals of the escaping gas though?